# Django: Race condition occurs in this block?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working with `django-nonrel` and `django-rest-framework` and I've got this view method who appends numbers into an array.

```
def add_number(self, request, *args, **kargs):
    row = self.get_object()                          # Gets the row from DB
    row.numbers.append(request.POST.get('number'))   # Modifies the column
    row.save()                                       # Save to DB
    serializer = self.get_serializer(row)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

If another client attempts to `add_number` his number at the same concurrent time, **Is it posible that one numbers does not remain stored?**

*Extra info*

This is running in `Google App Engine`, with `django-nonrel@1.5` and `django-dbindexer`, `Google Cloud Datastore` as database. Does `@transaction.commit_on_success` solve it? *(I believe it doesn't)*

Comment: But are transactions web scale? Anyway, transactions won't solve this, because you're not acquiring a lock on the row you're editing. I'm not that familiar with NoSQL, but to prevent race conditions you generally need a lock-get-edit-save workflow, in a single transaction. At the moment you're definitely missing the lock.

Comment: (If you could use a single `UPDATE` statement instead, that would certainly avoid race conditions.)

Comment: Maybe this works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123200/how-to-lock-a-critical-section-in-django

Comment: Well there is no `update` where I can **append** into an array/column. There are some methods for *increment* or *decrement*. And **Ale**, this case works with `NoSQL` database, so I'm not sure if those solutions works on `Google App Engine`. Actually I've no Idea how to get Erlang working on GAE.

Comment: I would suggest you look at CAS operations using memcache to create a lock.  You don't suggest by what criteria/key you are using in the implementation of get_number that that will be important.  You will possibly find transactions will solve the problem but django seems to abstract things a bit too much, and have never looked at django so can't comment further.

Comment: Well here is what I've found.. Ussually transactions wont solve this problem, but in this case, the app is running over `Google App Engine` and the database is google's `Datastore`, where transactions actually solve this `race condition` problem. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#Python_Uses_for_transactions