# Django local server: Atomic Database from a text file

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x

I made a Web app that takes in a text file, reads each line, takes the 11th character and saves it to SQLite3 db. How do I lock the database or have two or more separate tables while multiple requests are running?

I have added adding ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True to the settings.py in Django.
and I tried creating temporary tables for each request, but can't figure it out. I am pretty fresh to Django 2.2

My View.py

```
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'GET': 
        return render(request, 'home.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = DocumentForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                f = request.FILES['fileToUpload']
            except:
                print('\033[0;93m'+ "No File uploaded, Redirecting" +'\033[0m')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/tryagain')
            print('\033[32m'+ "Success" +'\033[0m')
            print('Working...')
            line = f.readline()
            while line:
                #print(line)
                mst = message_typer.messages.create_message(str(line)[11])
                line = f.readline()
        else:
            print('\033[0;91m'+ "Failed to validate Form" +'\033[0m')


        return HttpResponseRedirect('/output')
    return HttpResponse('Failure')




def output(request):
    s = message_typer.messages.filter(message='s').count()
    A = message_typer.messages.filter(message='A').count()
    d = message_typer.messages.filter(message='d').count()
    E = message_typer.messages.filter(message='E').count()
    X = message_typer.messages.filter(message='X').count()
    P = message_typer.messages.filter(message='P').count()
    r = message_typer.messages.filter(message='r').count()
    B = message_typer.messages.filter(message='B').count()
    H = message_typer.messages.filter(message='H').count()
    I = message_typer.messages.filter(message='I').count()
    J = message_typer.messages.filter(message='J').count()
    R = message_typer.messages.filter(message='R').count()

    message_types = {'s':s, 'A':A, 'd':d, 'E':E, 'X':X, 'P':P,\
                     'r':r, 'B':B, 'H':H, 'I':I, 'J':J, 'R':R }
    output = {'output':message_types}
    #return HttpResponse('Received')
    message_typer.messages.all().delete()
    return render(request, 'output.html',output)
```

When the web page loads, it should display a simple break down each character in the 11th position of the uploaded text file.

However, if two requests are running concurrently, the first page that makes the request gets an Operation Error; Db is locked. 
Traceback to here:
`message_typer.messages.all().delete()`

The second page will sum the total of the two files that were uploaded.

I do want to wipe the table after so that the next user will have an empty table to populate and perform a count on.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What you are looking for is a "lock". Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123200/how-to-lock-a-critical-section-in-django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock a critical section in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123200/how-to-lock-a-critical-section-in-django)